# How to pass join condition as a parameter to spark dataframe joins

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, parameter-passing, apache-spark-sql

I want to perform broadcast join as follow :

```
val z = main.as("m").join(broadcast(df.as("i")), $"m.sno" === $"i.sno", "left_outer")
```

But I want to pass join condition `$"m.sno" === $"i.sno"` as an argument.

I tried following ways:
First

```
val cond = """ $"m.sno" === $"i.sno" """
val z = main.as("m").join(broadcast(df.as("i")), $cond, "left_outer")
```

I found out parameter in join has to be column. So I converted it to column and tried.

```
val c = col(c)
val z = main.as("m").join(broadcast(df.as("i")), c, "left_outer")
```

I'm still getting error. How to resolve this.
NOTE: 'cond' variable will be String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If join column name is same then below syntax will be use full.

```
val joincond=Seq("SNO")
df1.join(df2,joincond,"inner");
```

If join column names are different then use below syntax.

```
val cond="SNO=SOME_OTHER_COLUMN"
df1.join(df2,expr(cond),"inner");
```

Answer (score 0):

What if we have a mix of columns with same and different names on which join has to be performed like below:

`Table A -> (a, b, c1, d1, e1)
Table B -> (a, b, c2, d2, e2)`

Join Condition -> `((A.a===B.a) && (A.b===B.b) && (A.c1===B.c2) && (A.d1===A.d2))`